# PLA infill/perimeter-layer to mimic real bone hardness

Tags: slic3r, material, medical

I friend of mine is in need to have human bone printed for educational purpose. Of what I understood they will use it for practicing drilling in it and thus need the printed bone to mimic a real bone. He specified that he wanted them as hollow as possible and with the same (or close to the) density of real bone

Is there anyone who had done a similar print, what material did you choose and how much infill/perimiter-layer did you use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a biomedical question

Comment: What you need to know is what the range of bone densities you'll run into, sorted by age, diet, gender, ... .  You will also need to know the macro-structure of bone, since it's not a uniform grid as produced with nearly all 3D-printer infill patterns.   This will not be easy.

Comment: I am voting to leave it open as it is a materials question.  Many/most of us are familiar with the hardness and density of bones.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you care about achieving a specific structure inside the "interior" part of a model to be printed, that structure needs to be *part of your model* rather than generated by a slicer. If it were me, I would programmatically generate a generic pattern for the pockets of hollowness in OpenSCAD over a region slightly larger than the bone, then subtract it from the solid bone. After that, slicer settings will be mostly irrelevant since it will be constrained by reproducing the layer outlines with lots of holes in them.

I haven't done this, or anything really comparable, but it should work.